# Arriving at contradictory results for this probability problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> I'm playing a game. I enter three different modes at different probability.
>
> For the first one, the probability of entering is $\dfrac17$ and that of winning is $\dfrac23$. For the second one, the probability of entering is $\dfrac27$ and that of winning is $\dfrac12$. For the first one, the probability of entering is $\dfrac47$ and that of winning is $0$.
>
> Find the probability of my victory.

Method $1$: $$P=\frac17\times\frac23+\frac27\times\frac12+\frac47\times0=\frac5{21}.$$

Method $2$: Draw a tree like this.

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCJQF.jpg)

I use the tick and cross to represent victory and defeat. And to incarnate different probability, I repeatedly draw. From the figure, $P=\dfrac6{13}\ne\dfrac8{21}$.

So the two methods lead to different answers. Although this has happened in probability like [here](https://www.baidu.com/link?url=YtViG7VIta2zu0Nqf1mC5ssfPukLc3ArGMXecfNvzkH-KUXimXY_duGYoKMP1im1l0QQBYJ7JAXVNya3WFRpVn3dg88DEcqQia-axFiIVhrww4WPVvFkc13g_wka3YPnIihlmRpC5hiTj1riTL0XjK&wd=&eqid=94237d9600086e970000000663660dd1), I still suppose that one of the solutions is wrong.

Comment: When I multiply and sum together your fractions, I'm getting 5/21 (which seems correct to me), not 8/21 or 6/13. Also, I am unable to see your figure.

Comment: $$\frac17\times\frac23+\frac27\times\frac12=\frac2{21}+\frac17=\frac2{21}+\frac3{21}=\frac5{21}$$

Comment: @HoldenRohrer It was my mistake in summing. Unfortunately, $\frac5{21}\ne\frac6{13}$. So the problem still exists.

Comment: Why are there $4$ $2$s in your tree and $2$ $3$s?  I think these counts should be reversed.

Comment: In your picture, the check marks and x’s are not equiprobable, so how are you computing with the tree (in other words, you can’t just count the checks and $x$s).

Comment: Agreed with Michael Burr that the figure is mistaken.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks. I understand that the ticks and crosses are not of equal probability.